# How to get vector of options from server.R to ui.R for selectInput in Shiny R App

Tags: r, shiny

My ui.R file has a selectInput like this:

```
selectInput("variable1", "Choose Option:", camps)
```

where `camps` is supposed to be a vector of options.  This vector depends on a sql query that runs on the server script and returns the IDs of the camps:

server.R

```
df1 <- getCamps("date")
camps <- unique(df1$idCamps)
```

When I run the App the ui.R does not know what "camps" is because it is only created in the server.R file.  How can I pass the vector of camps created in the server.R file to the ui.R file so that they are now the options to choose from in the selectInput selector?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to create an input object in server.R, and return it to ui.R as part of the `output` list:

In server.R:

```
df1 <- getCamps("date")
camps <- unique(df1$idCamps)
output$campSelector <- renderUI({
   selectInput("variable1", "Choose Option:", as.list(camps)) 
})
```

In ui.R:

```
uiOutput("campSelector")
```

Comment: I get ``` Unexpected character output for userTypes``` where userTypes is is a character vector nested within as.list() per the answer

Answer (score 0):

Easier way: Worked for me with barPlot() function. 
`names(dataframe_name[colm])` ,

where in my case `colm` was `colm <- as.numeric(input$parameters)`

and I was getting `parameters` from ui.r, where parameters was

`selectInput("parameters", label = "1. Select the variable from the U.F.O. dataset", choices = c("Shape" = 7, "Country" = 4, "AM/PM" = 3, "State" = 6))`